# Is there a way to simplify nested for-in expressions used in a for_each Terraform attribute?

Tags: foreach, terraform

Given the following code:

```
locals {
  roles    = [<a list of aws_iam_role resource objects...>]
  policies = [
    "AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly",
    "AmazonS3FullAccess",
    <...>
  ]
}

# Attach all policies to all roles
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "role_policy_attachments" {
  for_each = { for role_policy in flatten([
    for role in local.roles : [
      for policy in local.policies : {
        role   = role.name
        policy = policy
      }
    ]
    ]) :
    "${role_policy.role}-${role_policy.policy}" => role_policy
  }

  role       = each.value.role
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/${each.value.policy}"
}
```

Is there a way to simplify the expression inside the **`for_each`** attribute of `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.role_policy_attachments`?

E.g., in Python I would write the following more simple expression for which I cannot find the equivalent Terraform/HCL:

```py
for_each = {f"{role.name}-{policy}": {"role": role.name, "policy": policy} for role in roles for policy in policies}
```

Comment: Terraform HCL2 does not intrinsically supported nested map iteration, and so the general algorithm you followed above is still accurate dating back to 0.12. A better path forward here may be more efficiently restructuring your data such that the roles are keys of a map, and the policy lists are the values (unless this really is a situation where all of your roles are the same).

Comment: its a personal opinion, not a solution but if you have to use that many nested objects, its definitely better to refactor the code by separating variables or resources on some logical basis to make some abstractions. It's kind of abusive to use terraform as a programming language but again personal opinion can be subjective.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I don't think there's anything to refactor at the input level here. I have two list of inputs, roles and policies and I want to attach all policies to all roles. I prefer not to introduce additional variables unless they reasonably simplify the overall code. I might experiment with https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/setproduct#finding-combinations-for-for_each to see if it results in something simpler.